# How to decode metadata_storage_path produced by Azure Search indexer in .NET Core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Using .NetCore 1.1.2.

After successfully getting results from a search via Azure Search SDK, I am trying to decode the metadata_storage_path value.  I've seen people saying to use HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode in .NET or an equivalent in other languages [as seen here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93977c85-8eca-4278-a106-b29121ce4239/azure-search-base64-encoded-metadatastoragepath-incorrect?forum=azuresearch).

Then the question becomes, what is the equivalent in .NetCore of HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode?  With:

```
var pathEncoded = "aHR0cHM6Ly9mYWtlZC5ibG9iLmNvcmUud2luZG93cy5uZXQvcGRmYmxvYnMvYW5udWFsX3JlcG9ydF8yMDA5XzI0NTU20";
```

I have tried the following:

```
var pathbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pathEncoded); 
//Throws System.FormatException "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."
```

and

```
var pathbytes = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(pathEncoded);
//Throws System.FormatException - "TODO: Malformed input."
```

Interestingly enough, everything works just fine if I cut off the last charater in pathEncoded... What is the proper way to handle this situation with Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.1.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` appends an extra trailing character  to the encoded string. You're doing it right - just remove that extra character and use `WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode`. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732145/c-base64url-according-to-rfc4648) for details.

Answer (score 7):

I used the following function in asp.net core 2.1 to encode the meta_storage_path value from Azure search.

```
private string DecodeBase64String(string encodedString)
{
    var encodedStringWithoutTrailingCharacter = encodedString.Substring(0, encodedString.Length - 1);
    var encodedBytes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(encodedStringWithoutTrailingCharacter);
    return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedBytes, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add that you can also deselect the 'Base-64 Encode Keys' Azure search indexer option.

**NOTE:  Only do this for fields with no characters Azure considers invalid for document keys.**

[image]