# In Azure Search Services, metadata_storage_path is wrong

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have indexed the content of a blob container in a Azure Search Service index, using indexers, via Azure Portal.

When running queries in Azure portal, most of the documents have the correct `metadata_storage_path` but few do not. They have an extra character after the name, usually a '5'. It seems Azure appends a "1" in the base64 representation of `metadata_storage_path`.

**Therefore, the value of `metadata_storage_path` does not reflect the correct location of the file.** It has an extra "5" at the end.

In case anyone wonders, the files haven't been changed, removed or anything.

Did anyone notices something similar? Is there a known solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338134/how-to-decode-metadata-storage-path-produced-by-azure-search-indexer-in-net-cor/54952455#54952455

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you're not using the same base64 decoding algorithm used by the Azure Search blob indexer to encode the path. If you're using the full `.NET Framework`, use [HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokendecode(v=vs.110).aspx). If you're using `.NET Core`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338134/how-to-decode-metadata-storage-path-produced-by-azure-search-indexer-in-net-cor/44338785#44338785).