# Convert AES encryption java to Python

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes

I hava Java code that do AES encryption, and i would like to convert it so it work in python. This is a main class, i made initVector constants so it would be easier to see if it work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;



public class test {
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String ss = "pUypiz-7hJ0y_JtpKWaydp";
    String url = "";
    String toBeEncrypted = "";
    String initVector = "IqtY8jgALtjZNLM5";
    String encodedInitVector = Encryptor.encodeB64mod(initVector.getBytes());
    toBeEncrypted = "ch21979714702=put";
    ss = Encryptor.decodeB64Mod(ss);
    url = "i=" + encodedInitVector + "\n&a=" + Encryptor.encrypt(initVector, ss, toBeEncrypted);
    System.out.println(url);
}
}
```

And this is Encryptor class:

```
import android.util.Base64;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.util.*;

public class Encryptor {

public static String encrypt(String initVector, String key, String clearText) {
    try {
        byte[] value = clearText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key, 0), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(1, skeySpec, iv);
        return encodeB64mod(cipher.doFinal(value));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}

public static String encodeB64mod(byte[] bytes) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 2).replace('+', '-').replace(IOUtils.DIR_SEPARATOR_UNIX, '_').replace("=", "");
}



}
```

I tried to make it work in python but i am doing something wrong

EDIT:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
raw ='ch21979714702=put'.encode('utf-8')
key = 'pUypiz-7hJ0y_JtpKWaydp' #should be conveted to hex
iv = b'IqtY8jgALtjZNLM5'
cipher = AES.new( key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
print (base64.b64encode( cipher.encrypt( raw ) ).decode('utf-8') )
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing service, you have to make an effort on your own first.

Comment: I added python code, i tried to make it work but no matter how i converted key i can't get 16bytes of length

Comment: What happens when you run the python code?

Comment: "ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (22 bytes)"  i tried to base64 decode key but then i get  11bytes for key

Comment: Variables are cheap (free actually), don't reuse for different things and make they to name what they hold, `ss` does not seem to name anything..

Comment: Display and provide the variables `initVector`, `ss`, `toBeEncrypted` and add to the question. Display binary values in hex. Looking at these you should see the problem.

Comment: I can't change the "KUHMiz-7hJ0B_Jt6KWa1dg" this is my unique identifier, ss is the key in this case, i didn't change name of a variable because then i would need to change it everywere

Comment: I edited OP with the key in HEX, it looks like it's working but i miss last part in python

Comment: I tried with few different  'raw' messages and i always get last 22 character missing or wrong in base64 which is 16bytes, a am guessing that something is wrong with the last 16bytes when python tries to encrypt them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Python was that you need to use padding

`from Crypto.Util import Padding
 Padding.pad(raw, 16, style='pkcs7')`

https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/util/util.html

Unlike in java in Python you need to add that you want to use padding.

Answer (score 1):

You are requiring base64url decoding, which isn't the generic base 64 encoding: it replaces `+` with `-` and `/` with `_`. This is why the reverse replacement is performed in Java.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48262414/589259) is the correct way to decode it. Please upvote it *and downvote any answers that do not include the replacement characters **or** final padding with the `=` character*.