# Incorrect padding while decoding a Base64 string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to decode a Base64 encoded byte string to a valid HTTP URL. I have tried appending necessary padding (=). But it still does not seem to work.

I have tried the following code.

```
import base64
encoded = b"aHR0cHM6Ly9mb3Jtcy5nbGUvWU5ZXQ0d2NRWHVLNnNwdjU="
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
print(decoded)
```

The string `encoded` has a missing character as a part of noise. Is there a way to detect that missing character and then perform the decode operation?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302946/how-to-decode-base64-url-in-python

Comment: Not a duplicate. Have you checked my string?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide the expected output.

Comment: This means the base64 is corrupted somehow. If it's created by your function, check the algorithm once again. The only way to do this bruteforce the string as demonstrated by @SakibAlamin

Answer (score 2):

So, you have this `aHR0cHM6Ly9mb3Jtcy5nbGUvWU5ZXQ0d2NRWHVLNnNwdjU=` **base64** encoding of an URL  with exactly one character missing.

For the missing character, you've **64** choices: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789+/` (for **base64**) and **48** possible positions to put the missing character in `-a-H-R-0-c-H-M-6-L-y-9-m-b-3-J-t-c-y-5-n-b-G-U-v-W-U-5-Z-X-Q-0-d-2-N-R-W-H-V-L-N-n-N-w-d-j-U-=-` (`-` indicates the possible positions)

So, you've **64 * 48 = 3072** possible encoded strings. Either you can try to generate them by your hand or write some code to do the same.

Once you generate them, you can **decode** the string to get the **URL** using some built-in libraries & check whether this **URL** is **valid** or not. If you also need to know whether this **URL** **exists** or not, you can make an **HTTP** **request** to the URL & check the **response** **StatusCode**.

**Code:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    encodedURL := "aHR0cHM6Ly9mb3Jtcy5nbGUvWU5ZXQ0d2NRWHVLNnNwdjU="
    options := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789+/"

    length := len(encodedURL)

    for i := 0; i <= length; i++ {
        for idx := 0; idx < 64; idx++ {
            tempEncoded := encodedURL[:i] + options[idx:idx+1] + encodedURL[i:]
            decodedURL, _ := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(tempEncoded)

            resp, err := http.Get(string(decodedURL))
            if err == nil && resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
                fmt.Println("this URL is valid & exists: ", string(decodedURL))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you realise the question is tagged as Python?

Comment: Oops! Didn't realize it & I hope he gets the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

when the length of the unencoded input is not a multiple of three, the encoded output must have padding added so that its length is a multiple of four.

`len(encoded)` is `47`, it should be `48`, So append another `=`

```
encoded = b"aHR0cHM6Ly9mb3Jtcy5nbGUvWU5ZXQ0d2NRWHVLNnNwdjU=="
print(decoded)
b'https://forms.gle/YNY]\r\x1d\xd8\xd4V\x1dR\xcd\x9c\xdc\x1d\x8d'
```

Comment: That I tried. However, the URL generated is still invalid.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the missing character from the original string?

Comment: encode the original string to base64 and compare with your `encoded`